# Is it possible to delete data from webpage but do not delete from database?

Tags: php

I wish to know that whether is there any possible that can allow me to delete or hide the data on my php website but when I go inside my database, the record that is being deleted will still store inside the original database?

Comment: Add field to table `hidden` or something like that

Comment: Mark the record as "inactive"?

Comment: Put an `archived` flag against your database records, and only display records that aren't archived?

Comment: There are literally thousands of ways you can achieve this.

Comment: @u_mulder u meant that hidden in my sql?

Comment: @MarkBaker when i display the overall result, the data will shown also right?

Comment: @user3689699 - read every word that I wrote: `and only display records that aren't archived?`

Answer (score 4):

You have to add a deleted flag to your table

For deleting you set the flag:

```
UPDATE table SET deleted=1 WHERE id=xy
```

For geting the data from the database you have to check the flag:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE deleted=0
```